# Why NSNotification work slow?

Tags: swift

I know its interesting title for my question. Sorry for that. Here is my problem;
I am doing simple login screen (with facebook frameworks). If user wants to login with his/her facebook account, firstly he/she must confirm facebook page. And then i get their email addres, name, surname..etc information of user.

After that i just ask them password for my app. This password screen is a view. and opening on main view(not as new viewcontroller. its view on main view)  And after confirm facebook page then this wiew appear.

On this password view has 2 textbox and 2 button. textbox for paswword(and confirmation) and First button send request to my web service with user information. and other button is "cancel" button.

here is the problem. When user send request i create nsnotification for waiting respond. after getting respond. i want to this password view get hide.

here is the code:

```
@IBAction func buttonSave(sender: AnyObject) {
        var myObj = connectObject()
        myObj.sendRequest("http://localhost:8888/iphone/hearMe/index.php", param: "id=test123")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "actOnSpecialNotification", name: "sendDataCheck", object: nil)   
    }
func actOnSpecialNotification() {
        println("ok I got success respond from webservice")
        self.viewPassword.hidden = true /*This is my view */
    }
```

with this code. "viewPassword" view hided but not instantly. It hide after 10 or 15 seconds. How i can hide that view instantly after getting response from webservice?

Comment: so between the println and the hide is a delay?

Comment: and do you fire the notification on the main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether the 10-15 seconds is between the pushing of the button and the hiding of the view, or between the printing of "ok I got…" and the hiding of the view.

If the lag is between pushing the button and calling `actOnSpecialNotification()`, then the above code doesn't help us. We need to know what object posts the notification `sendDataCheck` and why it takes so long. Maybe it just takes that long to talk to the network. Maybe it posts the notification before you start observing it. You probably want to call `addObserver()` before sending the request rather than after (just in case there's an async operation in there).

If the lag is between printing the "ok I go…" line and hiding the view, then the most common cause of that is that the notification was posted on a background queue. You can't interact with UIKit anywhere but the main queue, and weird lags are a common symptom when you do.

(Side note: when in doubt, use `let`, not `var`. `myObj` is better defined `let` here. This helps protect against many kinds of bugs.)

Comment: this is a well written comment about no answer

Comment: you explain my question better than me.:). i got this message "ok I got success respond from webservice" instantly(just after i click the button.).so should "viewPassword" hide?

Comment: Check that you're on the main queue (look at the value of `NSThread.isMainThread()`)

Comment: Given it offers information aimed at helping the asker solve his problem, I don't see how you can say it isn't an answer, @Daij-Djan. Also, it is far, far too long for a comment.

Comment: it helped - so great - my comments did say the same but I didn't think I had enough information to write an answer -- this answer was pure guesswork (still ok) and and besides a vague opening featured even questions back at the OP ... I just don't see at as an _answer_ -- anyway it helped - all good